# MS Access Backend data corruption

Tags: corruption

I have an Access database that was designed and developed back in 1997 - 99. all user interaction is through forms and reports, there is no end user access to the backend tables.  It has worked flawlessly for the last 19 plus years.  Both front and back end are still in .mdb format, but the front ends which are local to the workstation and are replaced with a clean copy upon every login are running on Access 2016.  There are at a maximum, 6 users in the database at one time, usually there are only 4.

Starting about 90 days ago the back end would randomly corrupt when a request to write a record was made. The error message is “Database is in an unrecognized format”.  We have replaced old workstations and the Server that host the back end, in addition we replaced the switch that all computers connect to.  On the workstations that were not replaced Office has been re-installed and all updates applied to it.  The corruptions cannot be reproduced consistently, it happens in different forms and from different workstations randomly.  After the corruption, we have to delete the lock file, compact and repair the Back end and it will work just fine until the next corruption, and the data that was attempted to be written is there, so there has been no Data loss.

The back end data was rebuilt last year to remove the random primary key values, that were created when the database was replicated over a dial up modem back when the database was first developed.  The replication functionality was turned off approximately 17 years ago.  The back end has been rebuilt again from scratch, each table was created in a new Database and all the index's and relationships were rebuilt.  The data from each table was exported to a Text file and then imported into the new database.

There were no changes made to the front end in the prior three or four weeks before this issue started happening.  Just to ensure that it was not something in the frontend, it was rolled back to a version that was working fine in February of this year, unfortunately that did not resolve the issue

None of these steps have resulted in resolving the back end corruption, and if anything, the corruption is happening more frequently.  The only thing that works at this point is to have one user at a time in the database, as soon as the second user opens the frontend, the back end will corrupt within a few minutes.

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you
Steve Brewer

Comment: Maybe you'll have more chance on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Update:

This is a known bug introduced by one of the Office/Windows updates. See http://www.devhut.net/2018/06/13/access-bu...ognized-format/  for all the details and workaround/solution.